# Setting BIRT visibility for table based on alternative dataset size

Tags: dataset, birt

I have a BIRT report with two datasets and two tables bound one to each. I only want one table to show at once, based on the contents of the 'alternative' datset. So basically table1 visibility is set to hide if datset2 is not empty and vice versa.

Can/How do I script this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could call the BIRT Data Engine API in the beforeFactory script to check the second table's dataset to see if it has values and if it does drop the first table from the report.

```
//check if table 2 has data.  If it does drop table 1


importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api );
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.querydefn);
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core);


var myconfig = reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportEngine().getConfig();
var de = DataEngine.newDataEngine( myconfig, null );

var dsrc = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findDataSource("Data Source");
var dset = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findDataSet("Data Set2");

var odaDataSource = new OdaDataSourceDesign( "Test Data Source" );
odaDataSource.setExtensionID( "org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" );
odaDataSource.addPublicProperty( "odaURL", dsrc.getProperty("odaURL").toString() );
odaDataSource.addPublicProperty( "odaDriverClass", dsrc.getProperty("odaDriverClass").toString());
odaDataSource.addPublicProperty( "odaUser", dsrc.getProperty("odaUser").toString() );
odaDataSource.addPublicProperty( "odaPassword", "" );       


var odaDataSet = new OdaDataSetDesign( "Test Data Set" );
odaDataSet.setDataSource( odaDataSource.getName( ) );
odaDataSet.setExtensionID( "org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JdbcSelectDataSet" );
odaDataSet.setQueryText( dset.getQueryText() ); 


de.defineDataSource( odaDataSource );
de.defineDataSet( odaDataSet );

queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition( );
queryDefinition.setDataSetName( odaDataSet.getName() );
queryDefinition.setAutoBinding(true);


var pq = de.prepare( queryDefinition );

var qr = pq.execute( null );
rowcount=0;     
var ri = qr.getResultIterator( );       
while (  ri.next( ) )
{       
    rowcount++
}

ri.close( );
qr.close( );
de.shutdown( );

if( rowcount > 0 ){
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("Table1").drop();
}
```

Note that in this example Table 1 must be named Table1.  This can be done in the general properties for the table.  Full example is available here http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1542-data-engine-api-to-check-data-set-values/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's too late, this might help other people

You should make a test by using a column value in you dataset (count column, main column ...), then in your table `Visibility properties`, check `Hide Element` and `For all outputs`, push `fx` to write this code:

```
if (row["yourTestColumn"] == null){ 
    true /* when you want to hide your table *
} else{
    false
}
```

I hope that will help other people

Comment: Thanks very much. Was just starting to put efforts into creating a variable in the datasets eventhandlers. Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

keep a flag.Based on the flag load your data-set so that you can your data in your table at the same time based on that flag choose your table visibility.

Comment: So where do I define the flag - presumably in one of the event handlers? and how do I reference the size - <datasetname>.size()? Relatively new to BIRT (2.5.2 btw - a bit old I know) and have not had much exposure to scripting at all so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me:
(placing it in the '**beforeFactory**' script)

```
if (params["show"].value == 'N')
{
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findDataSet("MyDataSet").drop();
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("MyChart").drop();
}
```